# numeric or value error in Oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace
FUNCTION REPORT_GENERATION(  
 IN_STATUS IN VARCHAR2
 ,IN_USERID IN varchar2
)  RETURN CLOB AS 

  FINAL_RESULT CLOB:=null;
  OUTPUT_RESULT CLOB:=null;
 BEGIN
   /* My implementation. OUTPUT_RESULT contains large XML string */   
   FINAL_RESULT:=FINAL_RESULT||''||OUTPUT_RESULT; 
   FINAL_RESULT:=FINAL_RESULT||''||'</EXCEL_MAIN>'; 
   RETURN FINAL_RESULT; 
END REPORT_GENERATION;
```

When I am executing this function i am getting an error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
```

I am getting that error while returning the FINAL_RESULT.
length of FINAL_RESULT is 38123. If i replace FINAL_RESULT with some small string it is working without any issues.

How can i resolve this issue. Please help..

Comment: Try using the `DBMS_LOB.APPEND` function (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_lob.htm#i997432) rather than the `||` concatenation operator

Comment: @KenKeenan I tried DBMS_LOB.APPEND. Still getting the same error

Comment: @BobJarvis OUTPUT_RESULT is actually inside a loop. everytime it will be around 1000-2000 in length. I am appending it to FINAL_RESULT in each loop and returning FINAL_RESULT in the end

Comment: @Jasim - I suspect that when you use the string concatenation operator (||) you're forcing the CLOB to be converted to a VARCHAR2, and if FINAL_RESULT has a length of 38123 that will overflow the maximum allowed size of a VARCHAR2 (32767).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION REPORT_GENERATION(  
 IN_STATUS IN VARCHAR2
 ,IN_USERID IN varchar2
)  RETURN CLOB AS 

  FINAL_RESULT  CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
  OUTPUT_RESULT CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
 BEGIN
   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(FINAL_RESULT, OUTPUT_RESULT); 
   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(FINAL_RESULT, '</EXCEL_MAIN>'); 
   RETURN FINAL_RESULT; 
END REPORT_GENERATION;
```

A couple notes:

1. When working with LOB's (CLOB's or BLOB's) you should *always* initialize them to EMPTY_CLOB or EMPTY_BLOB.  Failure to do this will cause a pile of problems.  Play with the above code, changing EMPTY_CLOB to NULL to see what happens.
2. If you've done #1, you can't compare a CLOB or BLOB to NULL, because it's NOT null.  Compare an empty CLOB/BLOB to EMPTY_CLOB()/EMPTY_BLOB().

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the entire function in question.  From your comment earlier it seems you posted a much-simplified extract.  I have a feeling something else is going on that we're not seeing.  Thanks.

Comment: One other question: is the "real" function returning a CLOB or is it returning VARCHAR2?

Comment: Right, if you have that string going into a `varchar2` at any point it will fail with any string value over 32767 characters.